# Should the "angel of the abyss" be capitalized?

Tags: revelation, grammar, angels

I am discussing the doctrine of the Jehovah's Witnesses concerning the identity of Abaddon in Revelation 9:11. The names of persons (e.g. Matthew, Mark, and Luke) along with words that are part of certain titles (e.g. Michael the Archangel, John the Baptist, and Satan the Devil) are capitalized since they are proper nouns. However, some Bible translations render the term "angel of the Abyss" with a capital "A" in lieu of a lowercase "a" like in other translations.

Revelation 9:11 (NIV):

> They had as king over them the angel of the **Abyss**, whose name in Hebrew is Abaddon and in Greek is Apollyon (that is, Destroyer).

I find it quite difficult to discern if it warrants capital "A's". Is it a title? Some translators also opt to use a capital "A" when referring to the abyss such as in Luke 8:31 (NIV). Nevertheless, I am not sure if the abyss is specified. Should it be rendered as "angel of the abyss", "Angel of the Abyss", or some other rendering?

Comment: Bible grammar, most especially KJV Bible grammar, is very, very often nonstandard today. The Bible is not a good grammatical template. If "angel of the abyss" is a given epithet of a specific person, personage, or being that is used in lieu of their proper name, then you would capitalize each A, like you can say "the bard" to refer to any particular poet, but if you're using it as the given epithet it is for William Shakespeare, you capitalize the B and refer to him as "the Bard" (e.g., It wasn't until the end of the 16th century that the Bard's plays were published in writing.).

Comment: @BenjaminHarman capitalization has nothing whatsoEver to do with Grammar, as surely You know.

Comment: perhaps the reason it is not a capital is because it refers to satan himself (he is the star that fell from heaven). Bible translators are not wishing to give him credit that in any way might confuse with the Angel of The Lord?

Comment: Why is this listed twice? (https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60336/should-the-angel-of-the-abyss-be-capitalized)

Comment: @Dave Someone migrated the post from another exchange when I explained that I already posted it here. It is confusing to me (the subject). It is difficult for me to say whether or not it is a proper noun.

Comment: @Adam It is not about giving the subject "credit". All proper nouns start with a capital letter (e.g. "R" in "Ronald"). I am not at all sure if the text uses the phrase "angel of the abyss" as a title or if it is simply saying that Abaddon is an angel that comes from the abyss. I am confused as to why some translations capitalize the word "Abyss" in texts like these. Is it a proper noun now?

Comment: Since there are no capitals in the original Greek manuscripts (except in the Uncials where _everything_ is in 'capitals') this can only ever be a matter of opinion. The question then becomes a question of English [see 'Do I capitalize someone's role ?' on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204336/do-i-capitalize-someones-role)  which may well be a matter of style, rather than of absolute 'rule'.

Comment: 'All proper nouns start with a capital letter (eg "J" in "Jim")' begs the question, Tyconius. Both e e cummings and k. d. lang opted for lower-case spellings (and one for non-period initials), which choices should be respected by others; if we resolve this grey area by saying 'these then are not proper nouns', it becomes clear that 'should XXXX be a proper noun' has no clear answer. One can choose.  Forgetting what baggage the term 'proper noun' gets cluttered up with, 'should the “a/Angel of the a/Abyss” be capitalized?' is, as with the names of the author/... and the songwriter above, not...

Comment: an issue clearly connected with inviolable rules of English (consider 'Toys Я Us') but with choice. Some choose to lowercase Satan, for instance, as a sign of his cursed state.

Comment: I remain firm on it being a doctrinal reason. Ie it is not capitalised so as to ensure no confusion with Angel of the Lord (or God Himself). Translators are just trying to ensure that it is plainly obvious that is refers to the Satan and he has no godly status (note the lower case g in this case). BTW, if one was to read the Watchtower NWT translation, they do this exact same thing when talking about Jesus. They call Jesus "a god" (note the lower case "g"). Perhaps a JW has a better explanation for this habit?